# C# reference type conditional without comparator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I see this sort of thing in javascript all the time, iffy/falsy statements

```
if (someUnknownType) {
    // will check null | undefined | 0 | false | ''
}
```

but I've encountered this today in C# for the first time and I can't find seem to find the right words that I can search for this.

```
_existingInstance = getTheInstanceOrNull();
if (_existingInstance)
    DoSomeThings();
```

I thought it was odd since it didn't explicitly say `existingInstance != null`, so I decided to test out a couple things

```
if (null)
    DoSomeThings();

// Err: Cannot convert null to 'bool' because it is non-nullable
```

I double checked the return type of the method in question, and ended up testing this next

```
MyType instance = null;
if (instance)
    DoSomeThings(); // Roslyn says it's okay
```

Which I suspected would pass, since it's the source of my doubt. I then proceeded to test one last scenario

```
bool? doNotPass = null;
if (doNotPass)
    DoSomeThings(); 

// Err: Cannot implicitly convert 'bool?' to 'bool'
```

What exactly is being checked when a reference type is not explicitly checked against a comparator in a conditional?

I'be been working with C# for a few years now, so if it's well known, is this simply unpopular?

As a last note, I looked at the class definition to make sure there was no  operator overload, and I didn't see any

Comment: What does `getTheInstanceOrNull`? Is this by any chance run on Unity3d?

Comment: yes, this is in unity. It returns an instance of a class that inherits from `MonoBehaviour` or null if a ray cast fails

Comment: Any class can implement operators that support *conversion* to `bool`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Or the true/false operators. Interesting discussion in the duplicate

Comment: ah, I should have suspected it was specific to Unity

Answer (score 0):

first, bool? is not a reference type.  it’s actually a struct, which is a value type.  it’s a shortcut to `Nullable<bool>`.

so that will fail in your comparison.

this was throwing you off.